# Erro ao criar índice do tipo GIN

Tags: postgresql, índices

Ao tentar criar um índice do tipo **GIN** em uma tabela me deparei com o seguinte erro:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_descricao on produtos USING gin (descricao gin_trgm_ops);
ERRO:  classe de operadores "gin_trgm_ops" não existe para método de acesso "gin"
```

Pelo que tudo indica a sintaxe está correta e a coluna usada para o esse tipo de índice é *text*

PS: **Postgres 9.6**

Comment: Você está com o módulo pg_trgm devidamente instalado?

Comment: Verdade, vacilo meu. Faltou ativar a EXTENSION pg_trgm.